# R ddply row summary statistics

Tags: r, plyr, summary

For each row in my data frame below (defined by `FID_Bounda`, `NAME`, `DESCRIPTIO` & `SOVEREIGNT`) I'm trying to calculate the mean, standard deviation and the co-efficient of variation across all the values in each column starting with `crN`.

```
structure(list(FID_Bounda = 0:7, NAME = c("Bedfordshire", "Berkshire", 
"Bristol", "Buckinghamshire", "Cambridgeshire", "Cheshire", "Derbyshire", 
"Devon"), DESCRIPTIO = c("Ceremonial County", "Ceremonial County", 
"Ceremonial County", "Ceremonial County", "Ceremonial County", 
"Ceremonial County", "Ceremonial County", "Ceremonial County"
), SOVEREIGNT = c("England", "England", "England", "England", 
"England", "England", "England", "England"), crN1 = c(61.944107636, 
38.769347117, 0.810167027, 63.721241962, 191.046323469, 81.467146994, 
61.65529268, 288.751788714), crN10 = c(60.33595964, 38.326639788, 
0.834289164, 63.009539538, 185.25772542, 82.936101454, 61.985178493, 
304.951827268), crN100 = c(53.385110882, 33.530058107, 0.739041324, 
55.601839364, 165.604271128, 76.386014559, 55.591194915, 284.739586188
), crN1000 = c(58.397452282, 37.277298648, 0.820739862, 61.716749153, 
175.436497697, 82.461823706, 61.762203751, 321.414544333)), .Names = c("FID_Bounda", 
"NAME", "DESCRIPTIO", "SOVEREIGNT", "crN1", "crN10", "crN100", 
"crN1000"), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried to use the code outlined on [cookbook-r](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/) to derive these values:

```
cdata <- ddply(uadt, c("FID_Bounda","NAME","DESCRIPTIO","SOVEREIGNT"), summarise,
               N    = length(grep("crN", names(uadt), value = T)),
               mean = mean(grep("crN", names(uadt), value = F)),
               sd   = sd(grep("crN", names(uadt), value = F)),
               se   = sd / sqrt(N)
)
cdata
```

Which correctly counts the total N of `crN` columns but it gives the same mean, sd and se for every row. Any help as to where the issue lies would be much appreciated as the real data set has 1000 columns all with the same naming pattern of `crNnumber`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is not the perfect answer, but it might be worth using more up-to-date tools (equally I know the irony in this statement as my answer doesn't use `tidyr`). But the approach I would take is:

```
library(reshape2)
madt <- melt(uadt, 
             id.vars = c("FID_Bounda", "NAME", 
                         "DESCRIPTIO", "SOVEREIGNT"))
library(dplyr)
cdata <- summarise(group_by(madt,
                            FID_Bounda, NAME, 
                            DESCRIPTIO, SOVEREIGNT), 
                   N = n_distinct(variable), 
                   mean = mean(value), 
                   sd = sd(value), 
                   se = sd / sqrt(N))
```

This does produce the correct output

Answer (score 1):

The example in the cookbook is calculating mean and the other functions down the column not across the row, which is what you want.

A way of achieving this using base R is:

```
functions <- list(length, mean, sd)

d <- lapply(functions, function(y) {
  apply(uadt, 1, function(x) y(as.numeric(x[5:8])))
})

calc <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, d))
names(calc) <- c("N", "mean", "sd")

cdata <- cbind(uadt[1:4], calc)
cdata$se <- cdata$sd / sqrt(cdata$N)
```

If you have more numerical columns simply change the interval 5:8 appropriately.